# When I upload image or files in File field error occurs in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

When I upload image or files in File field of drupal site the below error occurs

[image]

My drupal site disk space is enough to upload file and tmp file and sites/default/file permission are 777. And admin/config/media/file-system Temporary directory is also correctly mentioned.But drupal is not allow to upload files. Please help me

Comment: Check for errors at: `/admin/reports/dblog`. Check your PHP error log. Make sure in php.ini `upload_tmp_dir` is set correctly.

Comment: there is no value in upload_tmp_dir. its necessary set path in upload_tmp_dir?

Comment: @Subarna yes , set path to tmp directory to ensure it save in right folder

Answer (score 0):

Go to: `Configuration -> Media -> File system` and click "Save configuration" (without changing anything). If some field gets red outline it means something is wrong with it's value (i.e. path doesn't exists, it's not writable or similar).